# Вывод определенного значения Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#

Всем привет, пишу простой парсер google на C#, используя Html Agility Pack. Мне нужно вывести определенное значение в тексте, который спарсил.

А именно (2 390 000 000).
Как это реализовать?

Код:

```
var content = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='mBMHK']").InnerText;
```

Вывод:

> Результатов: примерно 2 390 000 000 (0,39 сек.)

Comment: Наверняка в этом div есть еще вложенный div из которого можно выдернуть только нужное вам число.

Comment: @Bulson К сожалению, нет.

Comment: Значить в цикле по строке, как по массиву символов бежим и отбираем символы, которые являются цифрами, до первой встреченной открывающейся скобки. Или используем регулярку.

Comment: если это одна строка, можно резуляркой выбрать нужную часть

Comment: Хорошая идея использовать регулярку.

Comment: Как вариант: `var result = string.Join(string.Empty, text.SkipWhile(x => !char.IsDigit(x)).TakeWhile(x => char.IsWhiteSpace(x) || char.IsDigit(x))).Replace(" ", string.Empty);`. Значение `(0,39 сек.)` гугл отдает отдельным HTML тегом, а это значит вы можете его сразу отбросить при помощи XPath, тогда из кода смело можно выкинуть `TakeWhile()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете добавлять в ответ =) 
Спасибо большое.

Comment: Вы можете написать сами то, что у вас получилось. Пока писать ответы не хочу)